# Contrast stretching Equation problem

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, normalization

How to determine $a$ and $b$ in this equation. I know how to determine $c$ and $d$ by looking at the  intensity histogram. But what about $a$ and $b$?

$$P_{out}=(P_m -c)\left( \dfrac{b-a}{d-c} \right)+a $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the equation you are using

[image]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28image_processing%29

where `b=newMin` and `a=newMax` These values can also be found from your histogram. Usually you expand the new image to take up the full intensity range. The intensity range of your image is the X-axis of your histogram. If it goes from 0 to 1, then `a=1, b=0` if your hsitogram is from 0 to 255 `a=255,b=0`

```
a=newMax= most likely the last value of the x-axis on your histogram
b=newMin= most likely the very first value of the x-axis on your histogram
c=Min=last  nonzero element in histogram
d=Max=first nonzero element in histogram
```

Comment: Yes I understand it. But when I do not expand the new image to the full intensity range (i.e. 10-250) what is the logic there to decide that range? What I am asking is how to decide that newMax, newMin values? Is it just my preference to decide any range?

Comment: Well if you want to stretch the range from 10-250 your a=250 and b=10. Like the equation says the  a=newMax is the new maximum value a pixel can take. Does that make sense?

Comment: I should also add, this equation doesn't have to be used only for stretching. You can also use it for shrinking contrast. Say your current image uses the whole range 1-255 but for some reason you only want it to use 100-150. Just use 150 as newMax and 100 as newMin and you can shrink the contrast

Answer (score 0):

Assume we want the output image still in the range of an image, i.e. an integer in [0, 255]. If you know $c$ and $d$, then $a$ and $b$ can be determined by solving equations below.
$$
( \min\{P_{in}\} - c ){( b - a )\over(d-c)}+a = 0\\
( \max\{P_{in}\} - c ){( b - a )\over(d-c)}+a = 255
$$

Comment: Is the min{Pin} the minimum Gray value of the image? That is most probably 0 as most of the gray images have at least one white pixel

Comment: It depends on your image, normally a white pixel means ( 255, 255, 255 ), while black pixel means ( 0, 0, 0 ). You'd better find these numerical values for a given image.

Comment: Anyway so how to decide that range(in your example it is 0-255) of output image to be?  Is there any logic there?